# Forever cannot be installed

Tags: sudo, nodejs, npm

While trying to install Forever using this command:

```
sudo npm -g install forever
```

I'm getting this error:

```
npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.24","npm":"1.3.21"})

npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.24","npm":"1.3.21"})
npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.24","npm":"1.3.21"})
npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.24","npm":"1.3.21"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.24","npm":"1.3.21"})
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
/home/ali/Express/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/Mobile/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/Mobile/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ali: /usr/bin/forever -> /home/ali/Express/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/Mobile/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/Mobile/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ali: /usr/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever
/home/ali/Express/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/Mobile/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/Mobile/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ali: /usr/bin/foreverd -> /home/ali/Express/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/Mobile/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/Mobile/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ali: /usr/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/foreverd
forever@0.10.11 /home/ali/Express/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/Mobile/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ali: /home/ali/Mobile/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ali: /usr/lib/node_modules/forever
├── watch@0.8.0
├── colors@0.6.2
├── pkginfo@0.3.0
├── timespan@2.3.0
├── nssocket@0.5.1 (eventemitter2@0.4.13, lazy@1.0.11)
├── optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.5)
├── nconf@0.6.9 (ini@1.1.0, async@0.2.9)
├── utile@0.2.1 (deep-equal@0.1.2, rimraf@2.2.6, ncp@0.4.2, mkdirp@0.3.5, i@0.3.2, async@0.2.9)
├── forever-monitor@1.2.3 (watch@0.5.1, utile@0.1.7, minimatch@0.2.14, ps-tree@0.0.3, broadway@0.2.9)
├── cliff@0.1.8 (eyes@0.1.8, winston@0.6.2)
├── flatiron@0.3.11 (director@1.1.10, broadway@0.2.9, prompt@0.2.11)
└── winston@0.7.2 (cycle@1.0.3, stack-trace@0.0.7, eyes@0.1.8, async@0.2.9, request@2.16.6)
```

And Ubuntu generating recursive sudo directories with permission denied although I'm using `sudo` to run my command.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors? Where are they? There are warnings telling you about some modules expecting another node version then you have installed.

Or am i missing something?

Look here...

```
npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.24","npm":"1.3.21"})
```

Please try the follwing

```
sudo -i
aptitude update && aptitude -y upgrade
aptitude install nodejs
aptitude install npm
aptitude install nodejs-legacy
npm install -g forever
```